# How to show the 3-dots menu without ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to show the 3-dots menu without ActionBar. The information I've found so far seems to be incomplete, there're always hacks and, more importantly, it tells only about how to do that with ActionBar, whereas I need without ActionBar.

So how can I do that? If it's impossible to do that without hacks, I want to do it with hacks then.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "without the action bar" more please? Where do you want this menu to appear, and what behaviour do you want from it?

Comment: Let's assume : You do not want use actionbar(toolbar) and menu since 3-dot icon is result of *showAsAction*. If assumption is right, you should create a custom view and set ImageButton where you want to use 3-dot icon.

Comment: This also appears to be a duplicate of an earlier question you've asked. Please do not ask questions twice, but try to enhance the first question if you felt it didn't get enough attention. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863686/unable-to-show-the-3dot-menu

Comment: @adnbsr, sounds like what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy it from into your drawable directories from the SDK:

```
$ANDROID_SDK/platforms/$PLATFORM/data/res/$DRAWABLE/ic_menu_moreoverflow*
```

Note that there are several versions:

You could just reference it directly but there is no guarantee that it will
be there in future releases of Android.

So you could do something like this

```
 PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(YourActivity.this, 
                                 controlNearDisplayAreaOfMenu);
 Menu menu = popup.getMenu();

 popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_layout_for_popup, menu);
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OverflowMenuHandler());
```

Comment: you haven't understood my question.

Comment: @Mr.Mister you haven't very well explained your question. Are you just looking for the three button icon?

Comment: nope, for the way to show it without an action bar.

Comment: but where do you put the dots without the actionbars??

Comment: Do you want to use a `Toolbar` instead??

Comment: @Mr.Mister so where the heck do you want it to appear? You might want to look into a `PopupMenu` so you can place the vertical dot image anywhere as an `ImageView` and then when it is clicked show a `PopupMenu` but otherwise I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: @McAdam331, yes. Should I use ImageView or ImageButton better?

Comment: mjstam: in api 21 the "ic_menu_moreoverflow" doesn't exist and anything similar doesn't either.

Comment: @Mr.Mister that's up to you, you can use any UI item for it. Here is a *really* quick and basic tutorial of it: http://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example

Comment: Regarding the icon install, check this out: https://www.google.com/design/icons/#ic_more_vert